# Uncryptroot-unlock with dropbear doesn't launch my ubuntu

Tags: boot, mount, luks

I am facing an issue with a computer with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
My SSD Disk is uncrypt with LUKS. I have no access to this computer and I only do SSH connexion.
Normaly I uncrypt the computer using dropbear and the command `cryptroot-unlock`.

The computer had a issue of FileSystem full and it was in `Read Only Mode`. We reboot the computer, but now the command cryptroot-unlock doesn't close the dropbear connexion and doesn't launch Ubuntu.

My assumptions is that because the SSD disk was in read only mode, Ubuntu cannot be launches by cryptroot-unlock, but I have no proof about that.

Also we are in BusyBox v1.30.1 ash shell, so with limited number of command.

**Result of the mount command :**

```
# mount
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=32756372k,nr_inodes=8189093,mode=755,inode64)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=6573424k,mode=755,inode64)
p on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
```

I also tried :

```
# /sbin/fsck.ext4 /dev/nvme0n1p4
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
/dev/nvme0n1p4 is in use.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
```

Which is weird, as the disk is not mounted.

Comment: About the fsck: You tried to check the underlying disk, but your filesystem is on the LUKS container. Try `fsck /dev/dm-0`.

Comment: /dev/dm-0 was in used but I did `fsck /dev/dm-1` and it solved all my problems !
Thanks a lot !